# How to display multiple words from the same submission form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a submission form that can be used multiple times, which displays the words that are submitted next to each other.
So far I have been able to do the submission form and when the submit button is pressed, the word is displayed, but when the submission form is filled with another word and re-submitted, it takes over the previous word that was displayed.
Here is my code:

```js
function showTag(){
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
          document.getElementById("user_input").value;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showTag()">
<p><span class="tag is-info" style="background-color:#33475b;color:white;" id='display'></span></p>
```

I have looked around but all I have been able to find are "multiple submit buttons" solutions, which is not what I am looking for.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to have a intermediary variable that can store all the values:

```js
    const arr = [];

    function showTag() {
        arr.push(document.getElementById("user_input").value)
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = arr.join(' ')
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showTag()">
<p><span class="tag is-info" style="background-color:#33475b;color:white;" id='display'></span></p>
```

**Edit:**
For each submission from the user become a new element, you will still need the array to store the data from the user, but instead of joining the array, you must create a new element with the last item from the array:

```js
    const arr = [];

    function showTag(e) {

        arr.push(document.getElementById("user_input").value)
        phrase = document.createElement('p');
        phrase.innerHTML = arr.at(-1);
        document.getElementById('phrases').appendChild(phrase);


    }
```

```css
    p {
        width: fit-content;
        background-color: #33475b;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
</form>
<input type="submit" onclick="showTag()">
<div id='phrases'></div>
```

Comment: This works, but would it be possible for them to be in different spans so it is clear that they are two different elements - so there would be "white space" between the two

Comment: I am gonna edit the answer with the code that does that and the explanation